# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}2^{x^2+x}\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> **Question :** Evaluate - $$\int_{0}^{1}2^{x^2+x}\mathrm dx$$

**My Attempt :** First I tried to evaluate the indefinite integral of $2^{x^2+x}$ in order to put the limits $0$ and $1$ later on, but couldn't integrate it. Then I checked on WA and came to know that it's elementary integral doesn't exist. Now I moved one to using properties of definite integration such as $$\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x) \mathrm dx$$

But it couldn't help either. Can you please give me hint to proceed on this question?

P.S. - This is a high school level problem and therefore its solution shouldn't involve any special functions, such as Gaussian Integral etc.

**Edit** :  I asked my teacher this question and basically this was an approximation based question. This was a MCQ type question which has an option "None of the above" and it was the correct answer, since the other options were made in such a way that can be rejected by bounding this integral between 2 functions. For example we can use $$2^{x^2+x}<2^{2x} ~; ~x\in (0,1)$$ and thus can be sure that this integral is less than $3/\ln(4)$.

Thanks all for devoting your time in my question!

Comment: Looks to me like the gaussian integral you should be inspired by that integral to evaluate yours.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral

Comment: @Isham But this a high school level problem, and hence shouldn't involve Integrals like the one you mentioned.

Comment: $2^{x^2+x}$ **is** a complicated function.

Comment: @Khare It looks the same for me...write $ 2 \int e^{(x+1)^2 ln 2 } $ you will see the gaussian integral more clearly...these kind of integrals arent simple at all...

Comment: Inevitably, there is a link between this question and the Gaussian integral, which is easy to make out. However, I don't think the Gaussian integral, or it's evaluation falls under high school syllabus, although I knew about it.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown By complicated functions I meant special functions (which are not integrable) such as the one mentioned by Isham -- Gaussian Integral, I am saying that that we don't study about these functions upto 12th grade, it's where the problem comes from.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I too know about Gaussian Integral, but I can't solve this problem using that Infront of my teacher as we don't study this in school.

Comment: @Isham Yes, I do agree that there is a link between these both integrals, but may be, for the limits 0 to 1, there is a possible simple solution!

Comment: Only because I know, but if I am not wrong, in the syllabus for IITJEE the Gaussian integral is included. I know this only from friends,since I gave the IIT without looking at the syllabus, and that was four years ago.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг No, Gaussian Integral isn't included in the syllabus of IIT-JEE, I'm sure of that because I've read it's course from official website and a number of books for JEE, but Gaussian Integral has been mentioned *no where*.

Comment: Oh, I apologize in that case. I really think you should ask your teacher on this one.

Comment: @jaideep if there is a simple way to evaluate your integral then  it should work for the Gaussian integral too. It's the function itself under the integrand taht makes it hard to solve... There is no simple way to do it you may use a double integral or somethink like that ...

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг No problem sir! Sure, I'll ask my teacher and when I find the solution, I'll add answer to this question.

Comment: @JaideepKhare Thank you for the same. I would love to know what your teacher thinks is elementary.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I asked my teacher about this, and basically this was an approximation based question. This was a MCQ type question which has an option "None of the above" and it was the correct answer, since the other options were made in such a way that can be rejected by bounding this integral between 2 functions. For example we can use $$2^{x^2+x}<2^{2x} ~; ~x\in (0,1)$$ and thus can be sure that this integral is less than $3/\ln(4)$.

Comment: Oh, so that is the point. Thank you for replying to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot use special functions, then either numerical integration or approximation would be required.

For example, consider the Taylor expansion built around $x=\frac 12$ (mid point of the integration interval selected in order to tvoid promoting one of the bounds). You would  get 
$$2^{x^2+x}=2^{3/4}+2^{3/4} \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (4)+2^{3/4}
    \log (2) (1+\log
   (4))\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+O\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^3\right)$$ Integrate termwise to get 
$$\int 2^{x^2+x}\,dx=2^{3/4} \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \log
   (4)}{\sqrt[4]{2}}+\frac{1}{3} 2^{3/4} \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^3 \log (2)
   (1+\log (4))+O\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^4\right)$$ USe the bounds to get, as an approximation,
$$\int_0^1 2^{x^2+x}\,dx\approx\frac{24+\log ^2(4)+\log (4)}{12 \sqrt[4]{2}}\approx 1.91361$$ while Wolfram Alpha would give $\approx 1.93749$.

For sure, you could improve using more terms. For illustration purposes, suppose that we make the expansion to $O\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\right)$. We should get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \text{result} \\
 2 & 1.91361 \\
 4 & 1.93589 \\
 6 & 1.93741 \\
 8 & 1.93749
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Put $y = 2^{x^2+x}$

Integral becomes $\int_{1}^{4} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+ \frac{4}{\ln(2)}\ln(y)}}dy$

Again Put $\sqrt{1+ \frac{4}{\ln(2)}\ln(y)}= u$

Integral becomes $\int_{1}^{3}\frac{1}{2e^a} e^{au^2} du$

where $a = \frac{\ln(2)}{4}$

It resembles the standard integral $\int_{1}^{3} e^{au^2}du$

$$\int e^{au^2}du = \frac{-i\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{a}} \text{erf}\left(iu\sqrt{a}\right)$$

I hope you can take it from there

I am attaching the table of standard integrals for your reference

http://integral-table.com/downloads/integral-table.pdf

see page page 7, integral number 67

Good luck

Comment: By no country's standard, is this a high school problem.  Are you taking any specialised course that the standard is so high

Comment: I asked my teacher about this, and basically this was an approximation based question. This was a MCQ type question which has an option "None of the above" and it was the correct answer, since the other options were made in such a way that can be rejected by bounding this integral between 2 functions. For example we can use $$2^{x^2+x}<2^{2x} ~; ~x\in (0,1)$$ and thus can be sure that this integral is less than $3/\ln(4)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Using $u=\frac{2x+1}{2}$ yields an [imaginary error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html).